# How to get list of Integer from String

Tags: java

my string contains `Integer` separated by space:

```
String number = "1 2 3 4 5 "
```

How I can get list of `Integer` from this string ?

Comment: Have search for http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read the string one integer at a time.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(number);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    list.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: Just one question is this method faster or slower then method mention in other answers ?

Comment: All these examples will run in O(n) time. So the answer is there is no real performance difference. Edit: Actually, splitting the strings first like (suggested in another post), and then adding them to a collection will contain 2 x O(n) loops. This solution would be better

Comment: @hudi - I think that my code compares favorably in terms of speed with the other answers, but that can only be determined by profiling. The differences will be small.

Comment: @TedHopp - How about the String "2a11b20c"?? I would like to get the result list [2, 11, 20]. Thanks :-)

Comment: @ZinMinn - Well, you could call `scanner.useDelimiter("\\D");` which would tell the scanner to consider anything other than a digit as a delimiter. It would then treat the "a", "b", and "c" in your sample string the same as blanks and you could still use `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` as in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @TedHopp :-)

Answer (score 14):

```
ArrayList<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (String field : number.split(" +"))
    lst.add(Integer.parseInt(field));
```

With Java 8+:

```
List<Integer> lst = 
    Arrays.stream(number.split(" +")).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 7):

```
String number = "1 2 3 4 5";
String[] s = number.split("\\s+");
```

And then add it to your list by using `Integer.parseInt(s[index]);`

```
List<Integer> myList = new List<Integer>();
for(int index = 0 ; index<5 ; index++)
             myList.add(Integer.parseInt(s[index]);
```

Answer (score 6):

In Java 8 you can use streams and obtain the conversion in a more compact way:

```
    String number = "1 2 3 4 5 ";
    List<Integer> x = Arrays.stream(number.split("\\s"))
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Java8 Stream API map and `mapToInt` function you can archive this easily:

```
String number = "1 2 3 4 5";
List<Integer> x = Arrays.stream(number.split("\\s"))
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
String stringNum = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0";

List<Integer> poolList = Arrays.stream(stringNum.split("\\s"))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: what's the difference between first and second method?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,using `split()` method to make the String into String array.

Secondly,using `getInteger()` method to convert String to Integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String number="1 2 3 4 5";
 List<Integer> l=new ArrayList<Integer>();
 String[] ss=number.split(" ");
 for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++)
 {
   l.add(Integer.parseInt(ss[i]));
 }

System.out.println(l);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution just using arrays:

```
// variables
String nums = "1 2 3 4 5";
// can split by whitespace to store into an array/lits (I used array for preference) - still string
String[] num_arr = nums.split(" ");
int[] nums_iArr = new int[num_arr.length];
// loop over num_arr, converting element at i to an int and add to int array

for (int i = 0; i < num_arr.length; i++) {
    int num_int = Integer.parseInt(num_arr[i])
    nums_iArr[i] = num_int
}
```

That pretty much covers it. If you wanted to output them, to console for instance:

```
// for each loop to output
for (int i : nums_iArr) {
      System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Okay, simple modification:

First for loop: Sub out the int num_int for nums_iArr = Integer.parseInt(num_arr[i])

Drops a line of code. Is that enough or would you suggest something more?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to introduce tokenizer class to split by any delimiter. Input string is scanned only once and we have a list without extra loops.

```
    String value = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";
    List<Long> list=new ArrayList<Long>();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(value, ",");
    while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        String val = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
        if (!val.isEmpty()) list.add( Long.parseLong(val) );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

split it with **space**, get an array then convert it to list.

Comment: when I convert array to list with method asList I get array of string not Integer

Comment: @hudi you can convert those string to integer using 'Integer.parseInt()' method

Comment: I dont like this method becaue when in this string isnt number then occurs exceptions and I looking for some faster method to convert this not one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can split it and afterwards iterate it converting it into number like:

```
    String[] strings = "1 2 3".split("\\ ");
    int[] ints = new int[strings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
```

Answer (score 0):

You first split your string using regex and then iterate through the array converting every value into desired type.

```
String[] literalNumbers = [number.split(" ");][1]
int[] numbers = new int[literalNumbers.length];

for(i = 0; i < literalNumbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = Integer.valueOf(literalNumbers[i]).intValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a more general method for retrieving the list of integers from a string so I wrote my own method.
I'm not sure if it's better than all the above because I haven't checked them.
Here it is:

```
public static List<Integer> getAllIntegerNumbersAfterKeyFromString(
        String text, String key) throws Exception {
    text = text.substring(text.indexOf(key) + key.length());
    List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String intNumber = "";
    char[] characters = text.toCharArray();
    boolean foundAtLeastOneInteger = false;
    for (char ch : characters) {
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            intNumber += ch;
        } else {
            if (intNumber != "") {
                foundAtLeastOneInteger = true;
                listOfIntegers.add(Integer.parseInt(intNumber));
                intNumber = "";
            }
        }
    }
    if (!foundAtLeastOneInteger)
        throw new Exception(
                "No matching integer was found in the provided string!");
    return listOfIntegers;
}
```

The @key parameter is not compulsory. It can be removed if you delete the first line of the method:

```
    text = text.substring(text.indexOf(key) + key.length());
```

or you can just feed it with "".