# Is possible in Java to convert one String input to a list of integers in one line?

Tags: java

In python I use one line to convert an string in an integers list, by example:

"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" Is the input

`listOfIntegers = list(map(lambda x : int(x), input().split()))`

Then the list will be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

And In c# I use:

`var numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();`

Is a way to convert a string in a integers list in Java with only one line?

Comment: Whitespace is optional. You can do pretty much anything on one line, technically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get list of Integer from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009818/how-to-get-list-of-integer-from-string)

Answer (score 1):

Something like :

```
    List<String> source = new ArrayList<>();
    source.add("1");
    source.add("2");
    source.add("3");

    List<Integer> result = source.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

These steps you can follow and then implement the code that I show you

```
// Java Program to convert
// List<String> to List<Integer> in Java 8
  
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.*;
  
class GFG {
  
    // Generic function to convert List of
    // String to List of Integer
    public static <T, U> List<U>
    convertStringListToIntList(List<T> listOfString,
                               Function<T, U> function)
    {
        return listOfString.stream()
            .map(function)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
  
        // Create a list of String
        List<String> listOfString = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3",
                                                       "4", "5");
  
        // Print the list of String
        System.out.println("List of String: " + listOfString);
  
        // Convert List of String to list of Integer
        List<Integer> listOfInteger = convertStringListToIntList(
            listOfString,
            Integer::parseInt);
  
        // Print the list of Integer
        System.out.println("List of Integer: " + listOfInteger);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i tried to do it

```java
package examples;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SampleConversion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
        List<Integer> collect = Stream.of(input).map(s -> s.split(" "))
                .flatMap((Function<String[], Stream<Integer>>) strings -> Stream.of(strings).map(Integer::parseInt))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(collect);
    }
}
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't seem to have an input method that can be chained to other methods like in your python and C# examples, so I don't think a 1-liners is possible. You need to instantiate an object that reads input in order to do this in Java.

```
Console console = System.console();
String[] arrOfStr = console.readLine().split(" ");
```